# HTML not loading properly in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am trying to get the same result in Internet explorer as it is in firefox and in chrome.
But some how is not getting loaded properly.
For better explanation i will be attaching both the pic along with the code ,
How can I solve it.I have tried previous suggestion from stack overflow but nothing helped my case.

here is the pic taken from chrome

[image]

and this is taken from iexplore

[image]

the diff is easily visible.

Here is the code (HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Imperial</title>
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!--[if IE 7]><link href="css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!-- Contact Form CSS files -->
    <link type="text/css" href="./js-disclaimer/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!-- IE6 "fix" for the close png image -->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link type='text/css' href='js-disclaimer/basic_ie.css' rel='stylesheet' media='screen' />
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Load jQuery, SimpleModal and Basic JS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js-disclaimer/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js-disclaimer/jquery.simplemodal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js-disclaimer/basic.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="Body" style="zoom: 1;">
<div class="wrappers">
  <!-- home -->
  <div class="main">
    <!---- menu area--->
    <div class="menu_area"> <img src="./img/logo.png" alt=""> <br>
      <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="worldaboveworld.html" title="world">World above the world</a></li>
        <li><a href="spaces.html">Spaces</a></li>
        <li><a href="safety.html" title="safety">Safety &amp; Security</a></li>
        <!----<li><a href="#" onClick="callPage('plan');" title="plan">Plans</a></li>--->
        <li><a href="plan.html">Plans</a></li>
        <!----<li><a href="location.html" title="location">Location</a></li>--->
        <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="enquiry.html" title="enquiry">Enquiry</a></li>
        <li><a href="address.html" title="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        <br>
        <br>
        <li><a href="aboutsdk.html" title="SD">About SD Corp.</a></li>
        <li><a href="img/IE Bro20713 copy.pdf">ebrochure</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="IE Bro20713 copy.pdf" target="_blank">E-Brochure</a></li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">



        <div class="gallery-wrapper" id="vertical">

            <ul class="gallery vertical animate">
                <li>
                    <img src="img/gallery/1.jpg" alt="" height="600px" />

            </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/gallery/2.jpg" alt="" />

                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/gallery/3.jpg" alt="" />

                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/gallery/4.jpg" alt="" />

                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer" id="basic-modal" style="color:#000000;">© SDCPL 2013. All Rights Reserved&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="basic">Disclaimer</a></div>
<!-- modal content -->
<div id="basic-modal-content">
  <h3>Disclaimer</h3>
  <p>The content depicted herein is for general information and purely conceptual and is not legal offering nor will it be part of any binding document. The Developer reserves the right to delete, modify or supplement the content at any time for any reason without prior notification.</p>
</div>

<!--LOAD SCRIPTS-->
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/plugins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the style.css

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'manksansregular';
 src: url('../font/manksans.eot');
 src: url('../font/manksans.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/manksans.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/manksans.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/manksans.svg#manksansregular') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'manksans-mediumregular';
 src: url('../font/manksans-medium.eot');
 src: url('../font/manksans-medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/manksans-medium.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/manksans-medium.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/manksans-medium.svg#manksans-mediumregular') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'manksans-mediummedium_italic';
 src: url('../font/manksans-mediumoblique.eot');
 src: url('../font/manksans-mediumoblique.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/manksans-mediumoblique.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/manksans-mediumoblique.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/manksans-mediumoblique.svg#manksans-mediummedium_italic') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'manksansitalic';
 src: url('../font/manksans-oblique.eot');
 src: url('../font/manksans-oblique.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../font/manksans-oblique.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/manksans-oblique.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/manksans-oblique.svg#manksansitalic') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
* {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0
}
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size: 100%;
    background:url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat right;

    font-family:'manksans-mediumregular';
}
.shadowbox {
    background:url(../img/bg_show_effect.png) no-repeat center top transparent;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
a img 
{
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:40px;
    top:0px;
}
.wrapper {
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    min-width: 1024px;  
}
.header {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height: 90px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url(../img/menu_bg.png) repeat-x 0px 0px #0e0604;    
}
.main {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.menu_area {
    background:url(../img/menu.jpg);    
    overflow:visible;
    float:left;
    width:225px;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
    min-height:600px;
}
.menu_area ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:block;
    overflow:visible;
    padding:40px 10px 5px 15px;
    margin:0px;
    width:auto;
    /*overflow:visible;*/
    position:absolute;
    margin-right:40px;
    height: 231px;
}
.menu_area ul li {
    display:block;
    margin:0px 0px 28px 7px;
    margin:0rem 6rem 0.6rem 0rem;
    padding:0px;
    /*overflow:visible;*/
    margin-right:-30px; 
    width:auto;
}
.menu_area ul li a {
    font-size:14px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #7d7c7c;
    /*overflow:visible;*/
}
.menu_area ul li a.active,.menu_area ul li a:hover {
    color:#b6a062;
    overflow:visible;
}
.content_area > div#SectionContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
.content_area {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 999;
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
    /*float:left;*/
    overflow:hidden;
    height:600px;
    background-color:#fff;
        background-size:100%;
}

.content_area1 {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 999;
    top:-20px;
    width:1024px;
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:600px;
    background:url(../img/large_luxury05.jpg)
}
.content_area ul.home_slider {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:100%;
}
.content_area ul.home_slider li {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.content_area ul.home_slider li a img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:9;
}
.content_area ul.home_slider li a {
    color:#9b7d27;
}
.content_area ul.home_slider li a .trasition {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(../img/hover_effect.png);
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    z-index:999;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    min-width:200px;
    min-height:600px;
}
.content_area ul.home_slider li a:hover .trasition {
    display:block;
}

.content_area img {
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;

}
/*** slide content****/
.left_black_out {
    background:none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    /*background:none rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);*/
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height:600px;
    left: -660px;
    top:30px;
    padding: 100px 60px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    z-index: 9990;
    /*overflow:hidden;*/
    float: left;    
    margin-top:-30px;   
}
.left_black_out1 {
    background:none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 600px;
    left: 225px;
    top:30px;
    padding: 100px 60px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 800px;
    z-index: 9990;
    overflow:hidden;
    float: left;            
}
.left_black_out p {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align:justify;
    line-height: 21px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.left_black_out h3 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 27px;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.left_black_out img {
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
/*footer*/
.footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding:0px;
    display:block;
    text-align:right;
    height:32px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:normal;
    position:absolute;
    }
.footer a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000000;
}
.footer a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #000000;
}
/*.footer a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    float:left;
    border:solid 1px #9b7d27;
    background-color:#9b7d27;
    padding:2px 5px;
}
.footer a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}*/
.worlds img,
.plans img,
.SDs img,
.spacess img,
.safetys img,
.sustainibilitys img,
.contacts img,
.enquirys img,
.disclaimers img,
.locations img {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border-bottom:-20px;    
}
.Home,
.spaces,
.safety,
.plan,
.SD,
.contact,
.sustainibility,
.disclaimer,
.world 
{
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

/* This is the moving lens square underneath the mouse pointer. */
.cloud-zoom-lens {
    border: 4px solid #888;
    margin:-4px;    /* Set this to minus the border thickness. */
    background-color:#fff;  
    cursor:move;        
}

/* This is for the title text. */
.cloud-zoom-title {
    position:absolute !important;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:3px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;  
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:10px;
    top:0px;
}

/* This is the zoom window. */
.cloud-zoom-big {
    border:4px solid #ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
}

/* This is the loading message. */
.cloud-zoom-loading {
    color:white;    
    background:#222;
    padding:3px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.topmenu {
    height:90px;
    width:900px;
    margin-left:200px;
    margin-top:-80px;
    z-index:999;
    background:url(../img/menu_bg.png) repeat-x 0px 0px #0e0604;
}

ul li a{color:#7d7c7c;}
ul li.current a{color:#b6a062;}


.send{ margin:0px; padding:0px; background-image:url(../img/send.png); width:1580px; height:27px; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

.c {
    width:600px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
}
#flash {
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    /*background:green;*/
    float:left;
}
#embed, object, video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height:600px;
}



/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*  GALLERY STYLES
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.gallery-wrapper {
    overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; float:left;
}

.slideshow {
    overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; float:left;
}


.slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}

.slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}

.slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

.div-image
{
    overflow: hidden; position:relative; float: left; width:25%; height: 100%; 
    vertical-align:top;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index:12;
}

.div-image img {
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;

}

.plan-wrapper {
    overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative; float:left;
}

.plan-image
{
    overflow: hidden; position:relative ; float: left; width:40%; height: 80%; 
    vertical-align:top;
   max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.div-slide-effect{

    position: absolute; 
    float : left;
    left : -700px;  
    width:25%; 
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    background:none rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index:11;
    opacity: .8;

}
```

Comment: give fiddle and IE version, also styles and complete html are missing, but my quick guess would be missing display:block or wrong width definition in styles.

Comment: IE 11. no idea about fiddle.
I will put the style.css

Comment: and give us abilitiy to access HTML, becouse all we see is image and part of HTML with only menu and footer. It is difficult to analyze CSS from image...

Comment: i am completely new ,I dint understand which file u want ,I have completely copied the html code ,what else are u looking for ???

Comment: My last tip: most people will not help you until you give us working example from your domain or from http://jsfiddle.net/. Learn to use jsfiddle, its great tool. If you still expect answer, keep in mind, that is is difficult to do it without working example.